# Find trust setting of a login keychain using cmd

Tags: macos, command-line, security, certificate

Is there a way to find the trust settings of a certificate in login keychain using command line

I tried this `security dump-trust-settings -d`. But this only returns for the System Keychain

Also when i try with `security dump-trust-settings`. It returns `SecTrustSettingsCopyCertificates: No Trust Settings were found.`

Answer (score 2):

So found the problem

**Problem**:
I installed the certs using
`security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustAsRoot  -k $HOME/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db path/to/certs/ca.pem`

-d flag in the above command was adding the certs to admin cert store. Which isn't detected in the `security dump-trust-settings` command.

**Solution**:
Removing the -d flag fixed the problem while saving certs fixed the problem.

PS:
`security dump-trust-settings` actually returns the certs trust settings from local keychain if it either marked as trusted or not trusted. It doesn't return the certs if it's trust settings are marked as system defaults

[image]